# ajax loaded content event triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, jquery

I have a div in which I have a paragraph and a button like this:

```
<div id="my_div">
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <button class="my_btn">Click here!</a>
</div>
```

The content inside my div is loaded via Ajax. Now let's say that I have something like this in the header of my page to test the button:

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.my_btn', function(){

        alert('my button works!');        

    });

});
```

The problem I'm having is that everytime the content is loaded in my div with my paragraph and my button, when I click on my button I get my alert('my button works!') the same amount of time, meaning, if the content is loaded 100 times, I get my alert 100 times, any idea how I can fix this issue and why this is happening please?

Thank you

Comment: is that click binding code in your main page that contains the div?

Comment: yes the code is in the header of the main page

Comment: Looks like you bind a new function to the event every time without removing the old one.

Comment: how do i remove the old one

Comment: Ensure that the code is included in a place where it won't get executed each time you add a new button.

Comment: Use `.off()` to unbind

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are running your .click event in the ajax success? Why not placing it outside the Ajax call or does the element .my_btn refresh on a receiving new data?.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but should work

```
 $(function(){

   $(document)
    .off()
    .on( 'click', '.my_btn', function(){

    alert('my button works!');        

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you post the ajax call and how you are loading your div for a more detailed explanation.

That said, here is some sample code that seems to work fine.  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgxdj/1/)

```
<div id='data' style='display:none;'>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <button class="my_btn">Click here!</a></div>
<div id='target'></div>
<button class='load'>this load works</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.my_btn', function(){
        alert('my button works!');        
    });       
    $('.load').click(function() {
        $('#target').html($('#data').html());
    });    
});
```

Comment: I don't think `.html()` loads content by ajax

Comment: uhm, it really depends on what you are doing, which is why I asked.  But loading html from a div isn't all that different from loading it from ajax, depending on how you look at it.  All of that said... show me the code and response will be made more appropriate